# Obtaining real values from a WAV file c++

Tags: c++, c, audio, voice, voice-recognition

So I'm working on a very importan school project. I know now how to read everything from a WAVE file, including the data. The thing is that not only I need the real~ data values, but the sign as well. The file is 16 bps but I have no idea how to get an actual value, like, -365 or +19934.
This is what I do so far

> > leer = fread(&sbyte, 1, X, audio);

What number should I put instead of "X". 4?

I defined sbyte as a signed char, but signed char goes only from -128 to 127, which means that it doesn't give me the information needed.

I need those numbers to do some analysis. If you could help me here, cause I'm way too lost.

Thanks.

Comment: leer = fread(&sshort, 2, X, audio)

Comment: What other types besides `char` do you know? Also, look up `sizeof`. It might be useful.

Comment: 16 bits per sample means that 2 bytes per sample, obviously a char is 1 byte so it won't fit. Remember that the wave data is stored as Little Endian, so a short should be perfect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From this page: https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/

16-bit samples are stored as 2's-complement signed integers, ranging from -32768 to 32767.

In this case you want to use a 16-bit data type, which in C++/C is a `short`

```
short data;
fread(&data, sizeof(short), 1, audio);
```

This will read 2 bytes for you, and store them in the short. You will want to do that in a loop

Comment: This worked! Thanks! Although I still have a doubt. The loop I'm using looks like this `for (i = 0; i < csize; i++)`, where csize is the length of the data. Is it right or should I have i=i+2 instead, since I'm reading 16 bits not 8 bits like before.

Comment: Hi, yes, you can have `i+=2` instead of `i++` and make sure `fread(&data, sizeof(short), 1, audio+i);` Alternatively, take a look at the arguements for fread, the 3rd argument is the amount of data to read. Essentially, you can put `csize` there as long as you've allocated enough space for `data`. i.e. Similar to what LefterisE said below.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you need to read `header` information in the first 44 bytes as can be seen in the folowing link:
https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/

From there, you can get `BitsPerSample` and cast read bytes to `short` integer if it is 16, `char` if it is 8 or `int` if it is 32

Answer (score -1):

```
short[] data = new short[NumSamples * NumChannels];
fread(data, sizeof(short), NumSamples * NumChannels, audio);
```